# Scala parameterized function won't compile

Tags: scala, types, type-inference

Why won't this compile in Scala?

```
def fun[T: Seq](arg: T) = {
    val aValue: Seq = arg
}
```

On Intellij I get:

`Expression of type T doesn't conform to expected type Seq`

if `arg` is of type `T`, that is a `Seq`, and `aValue` is a `Seq`, shouldn't the assignment be possible?

Comment: `def fun[T](arg: T)(implicit ev: Seq[T])` is what you actually have after expanding syntactic sugar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the type bound wrong.

`[T : Seq]` is a *context bound* used as short cut to get implicit type class arguments and Seq is not a type class.

**Example**

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
def add[T : Numeric](left: T, right: T) = left + right
```

which is short for

```
def add[T](left: T, right: T)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]) = numeric.plus(left, right)
```

What you *probably* want to do is:

```
def fun[T <: Seq](arg: T) = {
   val aValue: Seq = arg
}
```

Where `[T <: Seq]` is an *upper type bound* and basically means *T is a Seq* or *T inherits from Seq* or *T is a subtype of Seq* (see [scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html) thanks to Victor Moroz).

**EDIT**
However, `Seq` takes type paremeters for the item type. So either you don't care about the item type:

```
def fun[T <: Seq[_]](arg: T) = {
   val aValue: Seq[_] = arg
}
```

Or you make it a second type paramter to `fun`:

```
def fun[A, T <: Seq[A]](arg: T) = {
   val aValue: Seq[A] = arg
}
```

These type parameters can ususally be inferred by the compiler, so you don'T have to explicitly pass the type arguments when calling:

```
fun(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: `[T <: Seq]` IMO means `T` is a subtype of `Seq` http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html